# Having problems with php rand function

Tags: php

I think I'm doing something very, very wrong.....

I know I'm doing something incorrectly with rand($a,$b), but I've found it difficult to isolate as I'm transferring from C++ to PHP

Here's the relevant piece of source code:

```
<?php
                    $r = rand(1,7);
                    if ($r = 1){
                    echo '<p id="quote">a</p>';}
                    if ($r = 2){
                    echo '<p id="quote">b"</p>';}
                    if ($r = 3){
                    echo '<p id="quote">c</p>';}
                    if ($r = 4){
                    echo '<p id="quote">d</p>';}
                    if ($r = 5){
                    echo '<p id="quote">e</p>';}
                    if ($r = 6){
                    echo '<p id="quote">f</p>';}
                    if ($r = 7){
                    echo '<p id="quote">g</p>';}
                ?>
```

Comment: You are doing something incorrectly with the equals signs.

Comment: use `mt_rand()` and `==` instead of `=`. The single `=` is the assigning operator, the double `==` is the comparison

Comment: A way to avoid making these mistakes is to have the conditions switch places, so instead of `($car == "blue")`, you would say `("blue" == $car)`. This will cause the parser to complain if you make a typo and do `("blue" = $car)`, since you'd attempt to assign a value to a literal. This is often referred to as [Yoda conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2430307/453331), since you're literally saying "if blue is car" instead of "if car is blue".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That entire block of code can be writtem much more simply as:

```
<?php
    $r = rand(0,6);
    echo '<p id="quote">'.chr(ord('a')+$r).'</p>';
?>
```

EDIT: By the way, what you were doing wrong is using `=` instead of `==` in your comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the value of $r each time...

It should be:

```
<?php
                    $r = rand(1,7);
                    if ($r == 1){
                    echo '<p id="quote">a</p>';}
                    if ($r == 2){
                    echo '<p id="quote">b"</p>';}
                    if ($r == 3){
                    echo '<p id="quote">c</p>';}
                    if ($r == 4){
                    echo '<p id="quote">d</p>';}
                    if ($r == 5){
                    echo '<p id="quote">e</p>';}
                    if ($r == 6){
                    echo '<p id="quote">f</p>';}
                    if ($r == 7){
                    echo '<p id="quote">g</p>';}
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($r == 7)
```

allways double equal signs